# How to deploy Flask app with live camera access on pythonanywhere.com?

Tags: python, flask, computer-vision, flask-restful

Testing Code:

```
import requests

# Set the API endpoinmt URL
url = 'https://api-kashifamjad.pythonanywhere.com/video_feed'

# Send a GET request to the API endpoint
response = requests.get(url)

# Print the response status code and content
print(response.status_code)
print(response.content)
```

Output:

> python test.py
> 200
> b''

1. Possible changes in code
2. any previous code or blog
3. any kind of suggestions

Comment: You'll need to use Javascript to get access to the user's camera: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Recording_a_media_element